# Tensor' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have the following message 'Tensor' object is not iterable." when trying to run my code, can someone tell me where is my mistake?
All the problem started because I need to normalize the the data that I am feeding. Therefore the problems comes from this part of my code:

```
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    avg_cost = 0.
    total_batch = int(total_len / batch_size)
    # Loop over all batches
    for i in range(total_batch):
        batch_x = tf.train.batch(X_train_norm, batch_size)
        batch_y = tf.train.batch(Y_train, batch_size)
        # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
        _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        # Compute average loss
        avg_cost += c / total_batch

    # sample prediction
    label_value = batch_y
    estimate = p
    err = label_value - estimate
    print("num batch:", total_batch)
```

Here is my whole code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X_train = np.genfromtxt('data/train500X.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
Y_train = np.genfromtxt('/data/train500Y.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
X_test = np.genfromtxt('data/test100X.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float,usecols=(14, 7, 33, 13, 32, 60, 16, 50, 18, 61, 17, 34, 26, 59, 85, 53))
Y_test = np.genfromtxt('data/test100Y.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
X_train_norm = tf.nn.l2_normalize(X_train, 0, epsilon=1e-12)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 5000
batch_size = 50
display_step = 1
# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 100  # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 200  # 2nd layer number of features
n_hidden_3 = 200  # 3rd layer number of features
n_hidden_4 = 256  # 4th layer number of features
n_out = 1
n_input = X_train.shape[1]
total_len = X_train.shape[0]

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None])


# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer


# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_out], 0, 0.1))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_out], 0, 0.1))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
# cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred - y))
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.transpose(pred) - y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(total_len / batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x = tf.train.batch(X_train_norm, batch_size)
            batch_y = tf.train.batch(Y_train, batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch

        # sample prediction
        label_value = batch_y
        estimate = p
        err = label_value - estimate
        print("num batch:", total_batch)

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", \
                  "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            print("[*]----------------------------")
            for i in range(3):
                print("label value:", label_value[i], \
                      "estimated value:", estimate[i])
            print("[*]============================")
    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `tf.train.batch` returns a tensor, which you can't feed to `session.run`. It'd easier to batch the data manually

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if I put the result in a session run will give me what I needed

```
batch_x_norm = tf.Session().run(tf.nn.l2_normalize(batch_x, 0, epsilon=1e-12))
```